# How code catches exceptions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, exception

How code catches exceptions (try, catch(...))?

```
push 0FFFFFFFFh
...
mov eax, dword ptr fs:[00000000h]
...
mov dword ptr fs:[00000000h],eax  
mov dword ptr [ebp-10h],esp
```

What this code mean in "head" of function, which catches exceptions?

```
mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 0
```

And this (in head of "try")? Function does not have any local variables.

Function:

```
int SUM(int a, int b)
{
    try{}
    catch(...){}
    return 0;
}
```

What store in FS segment?

Comment: Note: the generated code is very specific to VC++ 32 bits. VC++ for 64 bits (as well as all Itanium compilers) use the Zero-Cost model instead, which is completely different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value stored in `fs:[0]` is a pointer to a linked list of `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION` structures. Read here for more details:

[A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32 Structured Exception Handling, MSJ January 1997](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

How MSVC implements exceptions (on x86): https://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21

This covers both SEH (`__try/__catch/__finally`) and C++ (`try/catch`) exception implementation.

How MSVC (x64) and GCC (Linux/iOS) implements exception handling: http://www.hexblog.com/?p=704